# How to animate 'Bridge Edge Loop' effect

Tags: animation, mesh, animation-nodes, sverchok

I have two edge loops that are moving from animation.

[image]

I'd like to apply the 'Bridge Edge Loop' during the animation to keep them connected.

[image]

How can this be done? Can any of the plug-ins or add-ons like animation nodes or Sverchok help?

Comment: Looking to the second image I feel like you want to "animate" the `spin` effect and not the `bridge edge loop` effect. `Bridge edge loop` actually just creates faces between two edge loops, but `spin` creates the kind of effect you got on your second image. Indeed one of the best way to do this is by using the sverchok addon but I only know animation nodes and I don't know if I will be able to answer the question using sverchok, although using `AN` here would be a mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue I see with bridge edge loops and using a mesh for this, is that it will be very hard to control the deformation of the mesh as it moves It would require some rigging (bones and an IK system) to work correctly, in my opinion is too much trouble.

An alternative would be to use curves and hooks.

[image]

Here's a curve with some bevel. You can control the radius of each point separately.

[image]

To add hooks, select one of the control points, press the space bar and type hook, you''l get the option "hook to new object". That will create an empty. 
Do the same for the other segment of the curve and animate the movement of the empties.

[image]

Comment: That is a great capability! This answered the question the way the question was phrased. Thanks.

Comment: @EdTate By the last comment I feel that you were looking for something else.

Comment: Yes. I'll post another question that focuses on additional aspects.