# Logo Animation 2D

Tags: animation

How to do the logo animation like this (attached gif)?
See how the power circle moves and forms the letter K
and similarly how the power switch moves and forms the letter C.

I did power circle with build modifier but got stuck how the end of power circle will transform and create the shape of letter K or any other letter.

Similarly for Power Switch to transform to letter C (check how the shape transforms increases decreases and forms the letters).

[image]

Comment: Suggest use After Effects. Blender is not the right tool for motion graphics like that.

Comment: similar:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164162/text-to-object-animation/164536#164536

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/animating-appearing-extending-strip-with-gaps/63322

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with curves, Animating the Bevel start and End will allow you to create the movement within the path to complete the shapes. Add keyframes to control the timing.

Use a curve for each shape and animate individually.

[image]

For the change of shape you can use hooks on the curve control points, and just animate empties.

[How to animate A curve segment?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21233/how-to-animate-a-curve-segment/21234#21234)

and

[How to animate 'Bridge Edge Loop' effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84884/how-to-animate-bridge-edge-loop-effect/84898#84898)

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't seem easy to do with Blender, it may be possible with animations node (?), if you don't use them maybe you need to mix different techniques like curve bevels, booleans and maybe *Build* modifier as you did. For example for the C you can build the whole shape as curve, also create a square curve that will be your profile:

[image]

In the *Object Data panel > Geometry > Bevel* choose the square as *Object*, and keyframe the *Bevel Start* and *End* values.

[image]

It will allow you to animate both the 2 ends of the shape:

[image]

But for example, for the K letter, you can use 3 different curves, one for the circle, one for the K vertical bar, one for the K foot.